# Delete An Image() Object From Memory On Click Event Of Sibling Element — JavaScript

Tags: javascript, image, events, memory

I have an image previewer that uses the JavaScript `Image()` object to preview images prior to them being processed with PHP. I have a div that contains an 'x' SVG graphic that is targeted with a click event to delete the image.

In the code below at the bottom of the function it uses `evt.target` and essentially removes the parent element that each image is inside to delete the image if the user wishes to do so.

This all works OK on a visual level, but even if the images are deleted (and they are removed from the HTML), when the 'submit' element on the form is clicked to upload the images, any deleted images are still processed. From what I can gather the images are stored in memory and are processed from there.

I've tried setting the image itself (the `thumbnailElement` in the JavaScript) to null and setting its src attribute to an empty string but this isn't working.

What is the best way to prevent these deleted image previews from being processed?

In the code below I've swapped out the SVG graphic for the 'x' to the letter 'x' to make it easier to read.

**NOTE:** I've showed the entire image uploader below - but it is the final part of the JS underneath `// Delete Images` that is part I need help with.

Codepen: https://codepen.io/emilychews/pen/WNjZVGZ

```js
const dropZone = document.getElementById('drop-zone'),
    showSelectedImages = document.getElementById('show-selected-images'),
    fileUploader = document.getElementById('standard-upload-files')  

dropZone.addEventListener("click", (evt) => {
    // assigns the dropzone to the hidden input element so when you click 'select files' it brings up a file picker window
    fileUploader.click();
});

// Prevent browser default when draging over
dropZone.addEventListener("dragover", (evt) => {
    evt.preventDefault();
});

fileUploader.addEventListener("change", (evt) => {
    // Clear the already selected images
    showSelectedImages.innerHTML = "";
    // this function is further down but declared here and shows a thumbnail of the image
    [...fileUploader.files].forEach(updateThumbnail);
});

dropZone.addEventListener("drop", (evt) => {
    evt.preventDefault();
    // Clear the already selected images
    showSelectedImages.innerHTML = "";

    // assign dropped files to the hidden input element
    if (evt.dataTransfer.files.length) {
        fileUploader.files = evt.dataTransfer.files;
    }

    // function is declared here but written further down
    [...evt.dataTransfer.files].forEach(updateThumbnail);


});

// updateThumbnail function that needs to be able to handle multiple files
function updateThumbnail(file) {
    
    if (file.type.startsWith("image/")) {

        const uploadImageWrapper = document.createElement('article'),
        removeImage = document.createElement('div'),
        thumbnailElement = new Image();

        // 'x' that deletes the image
        removeImage.classList.add("remove-image");
        removeImage.innerHTML = 'x';

        // image thumbnail
        thumbnailElement.classList.add("drop-zone__thumb");
        thumbnailElement.src = URL.createObjectURL(file);

        // appending elements
        showSelectedImages.append(uploadImageWrapper)   // <article> element
        uploadImageWrapper.append(removeImage)          // 'x' to delete
        uploadImageWrapper.append(thumbnailElement);    // image thumbnail
        
        // Delete images

        removeImage.addEventListener('click', (evt) => {
            if(evt.target) {
                var deleteImage = removeImage.closest('article');
                deleteImage.remove()
            }
        })
    }

} // end of 'updateThumbnail' function
```

```css
body {
  margin: 0;
  display: flex;
  justify-content: center;
  width: 100%;
}

form {
  width: 30%;
}

#drop-zone {
  border: 1px dashed;
  width: 100%;
  padding: 1rem;
  margin-bottom: 1rem;
}

.select-files {
  text-decoration: underline;
  cursor: pointer;
}

/* image that is preview prior to form submit*/
.drop-zone__thumb {
  width: 200px;
  height: auto;
  display: block;
}

#remove-x {
  width: 1rem;
  height: 1rem;
}

#submit-images {
  margin: 1rem 0;
}

#show-selected-images {
  display: flex;
}
```

```html
<form id="upload-images-form" enctype="multipart/form-data" method="post">
  <h1>Upload Your Images</h1>
  <div id="drop-zone" class="drop-zone flex">
    <p class="td text-center">DRAG AND DROP IMAGES HERE</p>
    <p class="td text-center" style="margin: 0">Or</p>
    <p class="tl text-center select-files text-bold pointer">Select Files</p>
  </div>
  <input id="standard-upload-files" style="display:none" style="min-width: 100%" type="file" name="standard-upload-files[]" multiple>
  <input type="submit" name="submit-images" id="submit-images" value="SUBMIT IMAGES">
  <div id="show-selected-images"></div>
</form>
```

Comment: If element removed from DOM it's gone, unless it's reference stored in a javascript variable  in your case `deleteImage`. As of "submission" I have no clue what you are referring to. submission of what and how?

Comment: Use `Element.remove();`, then as long as you don't have any references to `Element` garbage collection can happen.

Comment: So maybe you could try use `removeImage.parentElement.remove()` without storing it in a variable, or even better: `removeImage.parentElement.parentNode.removeChild(removeImage.parentElement)`

Comment: @vanowm I've edited the question in regards to your first comment, and chaining the methods didn't make any difference.

Comment: you cant alter the fileUploader.files and youre just removing the thumbnails not files attached to fileUploader thats why it still submits

Comment: @dMd I just can't get it work with the comments and the answer given. I put a 250 point bounty on thinking I'd get an answer in relation to the code being used but it seems not.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

##### Problem:

You are not updating `fileUploader.files` when you `add/remove` an item.

##### Solution

Every time you `drop/remove` a file you need to update the fileUploader input. The first step is to create a function to handle the FileList object and change only two lines of your code:

```
//--> to create a FileList
function getFileListItems (files) {
  var transferObject = new ClipboardEvent("").clipboardData || new DataTransfer()
  for (var i = 0; i<files.length; i++) transferObject.items.add(files[i])
  return transferObject.files;
}
```

**Add** files during the drop event:

```
 //--> Updating files during drop event
 fileUploader.files = getFileListItems([...fileUploader.files, ...evt.dataTransfer.files]);
```

**Removing** a file:

```
fileUploader.files = getFileListItems([...fileUploader.files].filter(f => file!==f));
```

See a complete **working example**:

```js
const dropZone = document.getElementById("drop-zone"),
  showSelectedImages = document.getElementById("show-selected-images"),
  fileUploader = document.getElementById("standard-upload-files");

dropZone.addEventListener("click", (evt) => {
  // assigns the dropzone to the hidden input element so when you click 'select files' it brings up a file picker window
  fileUploader.click();
});

// Prevent browser default when draging over
dropZone.addEventListener("dragover", (evt) => {
  evt.preventDefault();
});

fileUploader.addEventListener("change", (evt) => {
  // this function is further down but declared here and shows a thumbnail of the image
  [...fileUploader.files].forEach(updateThumbnail);
});

function getFileListItems(files) {
  var transferObject = new ClipboardEvent("").clipboardData || new DataTransfer()
  for (var i = 0; i < files.length; i++) transferObject.items.add(files[i])
  return transferObject.files;
}

dropZone.addEventListener("drop", (evt) => {
  evt.preventDefault();
  // assign dropped files to the hidden input element
  if (evt.dataTransfer.files.length) {
    fileUploader.files = getFileListItems([...fileUploader.files, ...evt.dataTransfer.files]);
  }
  // function is declared here but written further down
  [...evt.dataTransfer.files].forEach(updateThumbnail);
});

// updateThumbnail function that needs to be able to handle multiple files
function updateThumbnail(file) {
  if (file.type.startsWith("image/")) {
    let uploadImageWrapper = document.createElement("article"),
      removeImage = document.createElement("div"),
      thumbnailElement = new Image();

    // 'x' that deletes the image
    removeImage.classList.add("remove-image");
    removeImage.innerHTML =
      '<svg id="remove-x" viewBox="0 0 150 150"><path fill="#000" d="M147.23,133.89a9.43,9.43,0,1,1-13.33,13.34L75,88.34,16.1,147.23A9.43,9.43,0,1,1,2.76,133.89L61.66,75,2.76,16.09A9.43,9.43,0,0,1,16.1,2.77L75,61.66,133.9,2.77a9.42,9.42,0,1,1,13.33,13.32L88.33,75Z"/></svg>';

    // image thumbnail
    thumbnailElement.classList.add("drop-zone__thumb");
    thumbnailElement.src = URL.createObjectURL(file);

    // appending elements
    showSelectedImages.append(uploadImageWrapper); // <article> element
    uploadImageWrapper.append(removeImage); // 'x' to delete
    uploadImageWrapper.append(thumbnailElement); // image thumbnail

    // Delete images
    removeImage.addEventListener("click", (evt) => {
      if (evt.target) {
        var deleteImage = removeImage.parentElement;
        deleteImage.remove();
        fileUploader.files = getFileListItems([...fileUploader.files].filter(f => file !== f));
      }
    });
  }
} // end of 'updateThumbnail' function
```

```css
body {
  margin: 0;
  display: flex;
  justify-content: center;
  width: 100%;
}

form {
  width: 30%;
}

#drop-zone {
  border: 1px dashed;
  width: 100%;
  padding: 1rem;
  margin-bottom: 1rem;
}

.select-files {
  text-decoration: underline;
  cursor: pointer;
}


/* image that is preview prior to form submit*/

.drop-zone__thumb {
  width: 200px;
  height: auto;
  display: block;
}

#remove-x {
  width: 1rem;
  height: 1rem;
}

#submit-images {
  margin: 1rem 0;
}

#show-selected-images {
  display: flex;
}
```

```html
<form id="upload-images-form" enctype="multipart/form-data" method="post">
  <h1>Upload Your Images</h1>
  <div id="drop-zone" class="drop-zone flex">
    <p class="td text-center">DRAG AND DROP IMAGES HERE</p>
    <p class="td text-center" style="margin: 0">Or</p>
    <p class="tl text-center select-files text-bold pointer">Select Files</p>
  </div>
  <input id="standard-upload-files" style="display:none" style="min-width: 100%" type="file" name="standard-upload-files[]" multiple>
  <input type="submit" name="submit-images" id="submit-images" value="SUBMIT IMAGES">
  <div id="show-selected-images"></div>

</form>
```

Working example

Comment: Hi @lissettdm Thanks for this - this works great out of the box. I do have an unforeseen problem though - the `dataTransfer` API has only just landed in Safari and it looks like I'm going to need to a fallback. Is that going to be real headache to potentially adapt/change ? Perhaps I should do that as a separate question?

Comment: Hi @TheChewy, your welcome,  maybe with a polyfill you can make it work

Comment: Thanks. I only found one polyfill which just doesn't seem to work. Although it's now in Safari (14.1), it's still not in iOS (14.7) which is weird. So annoying.  I might have to look at doing feature detection and if dataTransfer.files isn't supported remove the drag and drop element and just have the standard file picker/upload element.

Comment: I found this https://gist.github.com/saschanaz/293f9c7698776c8f3510aff703209d24..I didn't test it.

Comment: yes that's the one I tried. I couldn't get it to work.

Comment: I've found a solution. I'm basically going to have a file picker only on iOS and no drag and drop. The issue in desktop Safari seems to be with the removing of files - when you click to remove the images it duplicates the thumbnails and doesn't submit anything? I don't think this is to do with the dataTransfer.files (which is now supported on Desktop Safari) - do you know what might be causing this?

Comment: The issue in desktop Safari is that updating the fileUploader.files during drop event dispatch the on change event :/

Comment: One solution could be removing the on change event during drop event before updating the fileUploader.files and then restore the on change event

Answer (score 0):

This is because when a form submitted, it doesn't submit every HTML element in the form, but only values of `input`, `textarea`, pressed `button` and some others that have `name` attribute.

So what you need is clear the file `input` field too:

```js
const showSelectedImages = document.getElementById("preview");
const input = document.getElementById("test");

function updateThumbnail(file) {
  if (file.type.startsWith("image/")) {

    // image and 'x' to delete wrapper 
    const uploadImageWrapper = document.createElement('article')

    // div that holds the 'x' to delete
    const removeImage = document.createElement('div')

    // image preview element
    thumbnailElement = new Image()

    // 'x' that deletes the image
    removeImage.classList.add("remove-image")
    removeImage.innerHTML = 'x'

    // image thumbnail
    thumbnailElement.classList.add("drop-zone__thumb")
    thumbnailElement.src = URL.createObjectURL(file)

    // appending elements
    showSelectedImages.append(uploadImageWrapper) // <article> element
    uploadImageWrapper.append(removeImage) // 'x' to delete
    uploadImageWrapper.append(thumbnailElement) // image thumbnail

    // Delete Images when the 'x' div is clicked
    removeImage.addEventListener('click', (evt) => {
      if (evt.target) {
        var deleteImage = removeImage.parentElement
        deleteImage.remove();

        /* for single file input is enough clear value property */

        //        input.value = null;

        /* for multiple files input we'll need recreate new files list excluding deleted file */
        const dt = new DataTransfer();
        for (let f of input.files) {
          if (f !== file)
            dt.items.add(f);
        }

        input.files = dt.files;
      }
    })
  }

}

function updateThumbnails(files) {
  showSelectedImages.innerHTML = ""; //remove all previous previews
  for (let f of files)
    updateThumbnail(f);
}

function showform(form) {
  const list = {};
  for (let i of [...new FormData(form).entries()]) {
    const key = i[0].match(/^([^\[]+)\[\]$/);
    if (key) {
      if (!list[key[1]])
        list[key[1]] = [];
      list[key[1]][list[key[1]].length] = i[1];
    } else
      list[i[0]] = i[1];
  }
  console.log(list)
  return false;
}
```

```css
.remove-image {
  cursor: pointer;
}

article {
  display: inline-block;
}
```

```html
<form type="post" onsubmit="return showform(this);">
  <input type="hidden" name="myHiddenInput" value="blah">
  <input type="file" name="test[]" id="test" oninput="updateThumbnails(this.files)" multiple>
  <span id="preview"></span>
  <button type="submit">submit</button>
</form>
```

Comment: Thanks for this. Because the uploader also uses drag and drop I don't this will work (I didn't think I'd need to include that aspect). I've added a link to codepen in the question that shows the full image uploader.

Comment: Any image uploaders require a file input field. If you look at the HTML, you'll see `<input id="standard-upload-files" style="display:none" style="min-width: 100%" type="file" name="standard-upload-files[]" multiple>` Just remove `display: none` from it, and drag and drop an image, you'll see that that input will show the files.

Comment: I think the issue is with `oninput="updateThumbnail(this.files[0])` I changed it to `oninput="updateThumbnail(this.files)` to handle multiple files, but then nothing is uploaded when the submit button is clicked?

Comment: That was just an example. Your `updateThumbnail()` function only accepts 1 file at a time. The fix for the original issue is `document.getElementById("test").value = null;` aka clear the input field.

Comment: But my `updateThumbnail()` function doesn't only accept one file at a time? I'm confused?

Comment: Yes it is. It's parameter `file` expect an object, not an array. Perhaps whatever calls that function calls it multiple times for each file. Anyway, I've updated my answer to support multiple files.

Comment: Thanks. The code example above doesn't work though if I delete a couple of files and then submit what's left nothing happens when you click 'submit'

Comment: The example doesn't submit anything, it only shows in the console the form's data.

Comment: I think @vanowm answer is mostly correct, I've made example https://codesandbox.io/s/httpsstackoverflowcomquestions68492190-1womn?file=/src/index.js it works for both select and drop. I've added dummy function for test, to log what is going on, you need to delete it later to actually submit files. But there is big downside in this solution, it won't work on iOS at all. iOs does not support `DataTransfer` constructor. To make such file input work for all browser you would need to use `xhr` request to submit files, instead of native form.

Comment: @danila - thanks for this. On the plus side it looks like the DataTransfer API has just arrived in Safari - but obviously will still need to use xhr to submit the files for the foreseeable future. I'm going to look into that because it's not something I've done before.